# Excel VLOOKUP based on value of cell in named array

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a basic `VLOOKUP` that I need to expand.
`=VLOOKUP(A2,DVD,8,FALSE)`
It currently does as expected and grabs the data from the named array.

I need the `VLOOKUP`to return the value ONLY if the string/value in col 6 of the DVD array is *"IMG"*. If not, do not return the value.

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance for any assistance!

Comment: In future please ask basic formula questions at Super User

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(VLOOKUP(A2,DVD,6,FALSE) = "IMG", VLOOKUP(A2,DVD,8,FALSE), "")
```

This will result in two searches for `A2`, so you might want to use additional column to cache its position:

- =MATCH(A2, INDEX(DVD,,1), 0)
- =IF(INDEX(DVD,cache_cell,6) = "IMG", INDEX(DVD,cache_cell,8), "")